# Como remover popup ao abrir detalhes do produto?

Tags: magento

Estou utilizando um tema, e este tema ao clicar no produto na pagina principal abre um *popup* com os detalhes na página.
Gostaria de que ao clica em "visualizar" fosse direcionado para a página do produto ou então remover o sinal de "+" do preço do *combobox* (na página do produto não aparece o sinal de "+" pois consegui tirar, porém no *popup* aparece).

Magento versão. 1.8.1.0

[**Site para visualização**](http://www.aniixstore.com.br/)
[image: Exemplo]

Comment: Problema com o sinal de "+" foi resolvido. Alterado arquivo configurable.js comentado as as linhas no código a seguir: [link] (https://bitbucket.org/snippets/aniix_store/5y8jd)

Comment: para o popup acredito que seja este código [link] (https://bitbucket.org/snippets/aniix_store/eky4n) mas não sei como alterar para apenas direcionar para a página do produto.

Comment: Diogo  se resolveu seu problema, marque a resposta como a solução. Tenha um bom dia! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca trabalhei com Magento, mas analisando seu código da pra simplesmente fazer um "truque" com CSS.

```
.item a.product-image {
   display: block; /* adicionei esse */ 
   z-index: 1; /* adicionei esse */
   position: relative; /* adicionei esse */
   outline: medium none;
}
```

Basicamente ele faz o link sobrepor a `div` de visualizar popup.

Pra remover o botão vá na linha `4040` do `style.css`, na classe `.item .product-hover-box` e adicione:

```
display: none;
```

Faça o mesmo na linha `7943` do `style.css`, na classe `.mt-actions` e adicione novamente:

```
display: none;
```

Comment: Fiz a alteração no style.css mas nao adiantou, talvez eu tenha alterado o arquivo css errado.

Comment: @DiogoGumeiro As vezes está em cache o arquivo, dê um CTRL + F5 e verifique se essa `class` está corretamente no componente.

Comment: Notei que agora consigo clicar na foto e redirecionar para a página do produto. Só preciso ver de remover estes botões de visualizar e comprar.

Comment: @DiogoGumeiro Atualizei a resposta com outras 2 alterações pra vc fazer, da uma olhada :)

Comment: Funcionou. Muito obrigado, passei um tempo procurando como fazer estas alterações. Não fazia ideia de como remover aquele pop-up, nem imaginava que com css resolveria meu problema.